# Boto Import Error when running on apache

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, flask, boto

I've got an AWS EC2 instance running a flask app through apache.

I've installed boto via pip

I've got a wsgi file set up and if my flask app is a simple hello world it works fine:

```
#This works
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/hello")
def hello():
    return "Hello World"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=80)

#http://<PUBLIC_IP>.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com/hello
#Hello World
```

But if I try to import boto:

`from boto import dynamodb2
from boto.dynamodb2.table import Table`

When I visit  http://.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com/hello
I get an internal server error. Checking the logs reveals this

```
[Thu Aug 06 03:20:50 2015] [error] [client 203.220.19.142] mod_wsgi (pid=2988): Target WSGI script '/var/www/myservice/myservice.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Thu Aug 06 03:20:50 2015] [error] [client 203.220.19.142] mod_wsgi (pid=2988): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/myservice/myservice.wsgi'.
[Thu Aug 06 03:20:50 2015] [error] [client 203.220.19.142] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Aug 06 03:20:50 2015] [error] [client 203.220.19.142]   File "/var/www/myservice/myservice.wsgi", line 4, in <module>
[Thu Aug 06 03:20:50 2015] [error] [client 203.220.19.142]     from myservice import app as application
[Thu Aug 06 03:20:50 2015] [error] [client 203.220.19.142]   File "/var/www/myservice/myservice.py", line 6, in <module>
[Thu Aug 06 03:20:50 2015] [error] [client 203.220.19.142]     from boto import dynamodb2
[Thu Aug 06 03:20:50 2015] [error] [client 203.220.19.142] ImportError: No module named boto
```

Even though I've already installed boto (`pip install boto`)

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched yum for related stuff and by running:

`yum install python26-boto.noarch`

I fixed the issue